# linux command line in a c file

Tags: c, external-process

I'm writing a c-file in linux and I need to put 2 commands in my code but I don't know how to do this.

The commands are

> sudo hciconfig hci0 piscan

and

> sudo hciconfig hci0 noscan

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use

```
system("sudo hciconfig hci0 piscan");
```

or

```
FILE *pipe;
pipe=popen("sudo hciconfig hci0 piscan", "r");
```

to get the output of your command from the `pipe`, you can use the functions `fgets`, `fread`, ... you can read from the pipe like you read from a file